# UINavigationBarに置いたUIBarButtonitemの画像が青い四角になってしまう

Tags: ios, xcode

初めまして。
個人でiOSアプリを開発しているものです。

ナビゲーションバーにUIBarButtonItemを置いて、画像を設定したのですが表示が以下のようなただの青い四角になってしまいうまく表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像形式はpngで背景も透過してあります。
環境は 
`Mac OSX El Capitan`
`Xcode 7.1.1`
`iOS 7.1` (deployment target)
です。

解決方法をご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけますと非常に嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 以前、iOS7でUIButtonを使う際に、画像が青く塗りつぶされることがありました。こちらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。
http://program.station.ez-net.jp/special/handbook/objective-c/xcode5/button.asp
試しに私も同じ条件でUIBarButtonItemを配置してみましたが、問題なく表示されました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
試させてさせていただきます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageの**imageWithRenderingMode**に**UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal**を設定してみてはいかがでしょうか。詳細は下記をご参考ください。
http://nsblogger.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/04/01/uiimage_rendering_mode

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
うまく表示されました！